# How to move iCloud photos from one country to another?

Tags: icloud, photos

I have to move my photos/videos stored in iCloud from one country to another. I have both country's Apple IDs.

What's the easiest way to move photos/videos stored in iCloud to another Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to use [Shared Albums](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202786). Create a shared album for the source Apple ID and share it with the destination Apple ID.

On the destination, export the photos to save a local copy. Once exported, you can unshare/delete the shared album at source end.

Comment: Hi can you share albums between two different countries Apple id?

Comment: @SumitK What's stopping you from trying it? What reason can Apple have to disallow sharing a photos album between two users from different country?